# Mutually exclusive expandable panels (needs to work in IE9 and above)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function which essentially opens and closes content associated to a panel. Only one panel can be open at any time.

Here is my JavaScript, along with a typical HTML sample that it could work with:

```js
ts = {};

// Panels
ts.panel = (function() {


  function panels() {


    'use strict';


      var panel   = document.querySelectorAll('.panels-item');
      var button  = document.querySelectorAll('.panels-button');
      var content = document.querySelectorAll('.panels-content');


      // Reset all states
      function reset() {

        for (var i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
          button[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
          content[i].setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);      
          content[i].className = 'panels-content js-hidden';      
        }

      }


      Array.prototype.forEach.call(panel, function(el, i) {


        var button  = el.querySelector('.panels-button');
        var content = el.querySelector('.panels-content');


        // Buttons
        button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
        button.setAttribute('aria-controls', content.getAttribute('id'));


        // Content
        content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);


        function togglePanel() {

          if (content.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'true') {

            reset();

            button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
            content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
            content.className = 'panels-content';

          } else {

            button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
            content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
            content.className = 'panels-content js-hidden';

          }

        }


        // Hook up the event listener
        button.addEventListener('click', togglePanel); 


      });


    }


    return {
      panels: panels
    };


})();

ts.panel.panels();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.panels {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.panels-item {
  border-radius: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panels-button {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding: 24px;
}

.panels-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 24px;

}

.panels-title {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.js-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panels">

<div class="panels-item">
  <button class="panels-button">1</button>
  <div class="panels-content js-hidden">1</div>
</div>

<div class="panels-item">
  <button class="panels-button">2</button>
  <div class="panels-content js-hidden">2</div>
</div>

<div class="panels-item">
  <button class="panels-button">3</button>
  <div class="panels-content js-hidden">3</div>
</div>

<div class="panels-item">
  <button class="panels-button">4</button>
  <div class="panels-content js-hidden">4</div>
</div>

</div>
```

It does work, but I'm not confident with it. It would be good to have some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, the code looks pretty good. Definitely much better than many other JS examples in CodeReview. A few minor points can be made though.

**DRY - Don't repeat yourself**

At the very minimum, you can reuse some code by encapsulating it into a function.

You can define `setPanelVisibilityState` which will be responsible for the details of showing/hiding a section. The decision on whether a button/panel should be visible or not remains in the control of the caller...

**Variable naming**

Similarly, I'm unsure if the selectors `'.panels-button'` and `'.panels-content'` more than in one place...

I personally am a big enemy of variables like `i`, `j`, `c`, and so on. It's not so difficult to spell it out: `panelIndex`.

**IE is a beast**

As far as IE page renderer goes, I can't provide much feedback because I don't deal with it.

---

```
function togglePanel() {
    const showContent = content.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'true';
    reset();
    setPanelVisibilityState(false, button, content);
}

function reset() {
    for (var panelIndex = 0; panelIndex < panel.length; panelIndex++)
        setPanelVisibilityState(false, button[panelIndex], content[panelIndex]);
}

function setPanelVisibilityState(isVisible, button, content) {
    button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', isVisible);
    content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', !isVisible);
    content.className = isVisible ? 'panels-content' : 'panels-content js-hidden';
}
```

Comment: The `const` won't work in IE9. It will work in IE11 and Edge, but not in IE9, as required in the question. You can read the compatibility table on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Also, instead of `content.className = isVisible ? 'panels-content' : 'panels-content js-hidden';`, you can write `content.className = 'panels-content' + (isVisible ? '' : ' js-hidden');` or use the `content.classList.add('js-hidden')`/`content.classList.remove('js-hidden')` to kame it more solid, in case you need to add more classes in the future, with a polyfill for IE9. Or just `content.className += ' js-hidden'` and `content.className.replace(/\s+js-hidden(?=\s|$)/g, '');`. The added benefict is that other classes will be kept, in case they need to be added in the future.

Comment: Hi Ismael I was aware of the const attribute :) Thanks.
It would be good to see this in a code snippet running...